# How to specify zeroeth argument

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script that starts the tcsh interpreter as a login shell and has it execute `my_command`.  The tcsh man page says that there are two ways to start a login shell.  The first is to use `/bin/tcsh -l` with no other arguments.  Not an option, because I need the shell to execute `my_command`.  The second is to specify a dash (`-`) as the zeroeth argument.

Now the bash `exec` command with the `-l` option does exactly this, and in fact the following works perfectly:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec -l /bin/tcsh -c my_command
```

Except... I can't use `exec` because I need the script to come back and do some other things afterwards!  So how can I specify `-` as the zeroeth argument to `/bin/tcsh` without using `exec`?

Answer (score 2):

You can enclose the `exec` command into a sub-shell of your script.

```
#!/bin/bash
(exec -l /bin/tcsh -c my_command)
# ... whatever else you need to do after the command is done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a wrapper (w.sh) script that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec -l /bin/tcsh -c my_command
```

and execute w.sh in your main script.

Comment: Giving commands filename extensions is not a best practice -- this should just be `w`, not `w.sh`, or you're creating headaches if it's ever rewritten to C (to allow the setuid bit to be set, for instance, which it can't be on scripts).